# Why won't Internet Explorer 11 accept this clickTAG flash variable?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, internet-explorer-11, google-dfp

The code that Google DFP generates for Flash-banners doesn't work in Internet Explorer 11. The problem is that the "clickTAG" variable is not read (it's defined as "undefined").

If I run IE11 in emulated IE10-mode, the banner will work.

My question is if anybody can see if this code below has any problems.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
a:link { color: #000000 }a:visited { color: #000000 }a:hover { color: #000000 }a:active { color: #000000 }  -->
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
(function(){window.ss=function(){};})();(function(){var c=function(a,e,h){var b=document;b.addEventListener?b.addEventListener(a,e,h||!1):b.attachEvent&&b.attachEvent("on"+a,e)};var d,f=!1,g=!1;c("mousedown",function(){f=!0});c("keydown",function(){g=!0});document.addEventListener&&c("click",function(a){d=a},!0);window.accbk=function(){var a=d?d:window.event;return a?f||g?!1:(a.preventDefault?a.preventDefault():a.returnValue=!1,!0):!1};})();function st(id) {var a = document.getElementById(id);if (a) {}}function ha(a,x){  if (accbk()) return;}function ca(a) {window.open(document.getElementById(a).href);}function ia(a,e,x) {if (accbk()) return;}function ga(o,e,x) {if (document.getElementById) {var a=o.id.substring(1),p="",r="",g=e.target,t,f,h;if (g) {t=g.id;f=g.parentNode;if (f) {p=f.id;h=f.parentNode;if (h)r=h.id;}} else {h=e.srcElement;f=h.parentNode;if (f)p=f.id;t=h.id;}if (t==a||p==a||r==a)return true;ia(a,e,x);window.open(document.getElementById(a).href);}}
//-->
</script>
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">
 body.c4 {background:transparent}
 div.c3 {position:relative;width:990px;height:240px;z-index:1000}
 div.c2 {position:relative;z-index:1001;width:990px}
 div.c1 {position:absolute;left:0px;z-index:1001}
</style>
</head>
<body class="c4">
<div id="google_flash_inline_div" class="c2">
<div id="google_flash_div" class="c1"><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="google_flash_obj" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" width="990" height="240"><param name="movie" value="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/imgad?id=CICAgICQv7mzShDeBxjwASgBMggY7LA9fUdj5g">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="never">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="FlashVars" value="clickTAG=http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/aclk%3Fsa%3Dl%26ai%3DCu9aee9GNUsPOFoS-yAOUhoGwAQEAexABILlgKARQ7pa9qv______AYgBAZABAMABAsgBBOACAagDAaoEVU_QlAYttWO5-9IxgKZ4VN1XHdRio1XcLTcx9QQf8tVpX1PUExFkbtCwGDDpSY9K8rNfS-Wuk70W-FbO01WTo0Ulq5ZEbrFMQ3RQDQ5xIESl-2LaEpe4BAE%26preview%3D%26num%3D1%26sig%3DAOD64_0pjWqfH6mwz0BOadU_gncO7GRTjQ%26client%3Dca-gfp-rama1%26adurl%3Dhttp://www.jalmersur.se">
<object data="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/imgad?id=CICAgICQv7mzShDeBxjwASgBMggY7LA9fUdj5g" id="google_flash_embed" width="990" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></object></object></div>
</div>
<div class="c3"></div>
<!--[if IE]><script language="javascript" src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/inject_object_div.js"> </script><![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

Running example: https://partner.googleadservices.com/gampad/ads?client=ca-gfp-rama1&gct=PwwFS2Vs1nEKcwsYBCAAMgA6AEoAaOienP080AGAgICAkL-5s0qaAx1hcHBsaWNhdGlvbi94LXNob2Nrd2F2ZS1mbGFzaKgD1AewA_AB0AMAgATeB4gE8AGgBALQDxXaEBdodHRwOi8vd3d3LmphbG1lcnN1ci5zZQz4DAEYkZ63lAUoADCRuuybBTgAWAFqBl9ibGFua3DXs7iFBQ&height=240&width=990

Comment: I'm actually facing the same problem with Firefox 25.0 and 26.0 on Mac.. My ads are not clickable in those browsers.. Is this a known issue at Google?

Comment: Interesting. I cannot replicate this problem in FF 25.01, Mac ...

Comment: Seriously, this is still an issue nearly 2 years later?  How has Google not addressed this!?

Answer (score 0):

One solution for Google DFP is to use the creative template called "Flash banner with optional third party tracking". It's a bit more advanced and inconvenient to use, but it's the best I've come up with for the moment.